# SFINAE with template pack: disabling member if no template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, enums, sfinae

I would like to define a class, with an optional template parameter such that:

- if the parameter exists and it is an enum class, defines an
  operator()
- the class can be istantiated without the additional    template
  parameter (in which case operator() does not exists)

The goal is to allow access to an array element through an optional enum class.

Code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int N, typename... T>
class data {
  int x[N];

  template <typename T0, typename... T1>
  struct enum_wrapper {
    typedef T0 type;
  };
public:

  template <bool activate = (sizeof...(T) > 0)>
  std::enable_if_t<activate, int>&
  operator()(const typename enum_wrapper<T...>::type& e)
      { return x[static_cast<std::size_t>(e)]; }
};
int main()
{
  data<3> a;
  return 0;
}
```

The purpose of enum_wrapper is to single out the first parameter in the pack `typename... T`.

The code compiled with `g++ -std=c++14` gives an error

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be at least 1)
```

on the definition of operator(). This is because `enum_wrapper<T...>::type` is not defined when data is istantiated with a single parameter `<3>`.
However, the template parameter `bool activate` in the definition of `operator()` and its return type `std::enable_if_t<activate, int>` is meant to prevent the instantation of `operator()` when the parameter pack `typename... T` is empty.
Why the definition of `operator()` is not simply discarded under SFINAE?

Also, I would like to further eliminate operator() when `enum_wrapper::type` is not an `enum class`, using `std::is_enum`.
Where a condition like

```
std::enable_if<std::is_enum_v<(enum_wrapper<T...>::type)>>
```

should be inserted to make SFINAE work?

Comment: I would say -- instead of futzing with `std::enable_if` and making `operator()` a template it should be cleaner to stick a `static_assert` inside the `operator()`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - Define "cleaner". If the OP has to manage overloads, SFINAE is the only way. A static assert will cause an error, instead of gracefully ignoring the bad overload.

Comment: There's no mention of an overloaded `()`. Just a single working `()` operator, that's how I parse it. It should be simpler not to use a parameter pack, but instead a single template parameter, `typename E=void`, then have a `static_assert` that calls `std::is_enum_v`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - My parse is that the generated overload should be gracefully removed. If you suspect the OP is going about his goal the wrong way, ask for a clarification about the goal. Don't assume a goal and make broad statements about "futzing". You could quite easily be proven wrong.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Thanks for your comment. I would indeed prefer to drop out the definition of ```operator()``` via SFINAE, when not valid; as noticed by @StoryTeller, this would allow more flexibility, for instance in overloading ```operator()```.Using a default template parameter in ```enum_wrapper``` is a viable option, essentially equivalent to the solution posted below by @AndyG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the argument type to `operator()` doesn't depend on the template arguments (to `operator()`)

You can make it depend via an indirection that specifies a new parameter pack that must be the same as the class' (unfortunately we cannot default a parameter pack otherwise we would)

```
template <bool activate = (sizeof...(T) > 0), typename... U>
std::enable_if_t<activate && std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, U>...>, int>&
operator()(const typename enum_wrapper<U...>::type& e)
{ return x[static_cast<std::size_t>(e)]; }
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/O1y0MOfsJ7CzkLFf)

---

I suppose I have some concerns as to how'd you actually plan on calling `operator()`, since `enum_wrapper` is private within the class. I think what you're really interested in is receiving a type that is the same as `enum_wrapper<T...>::type`. What is easiest here is to simply make a specialization for `enum_wrapper` for an empty `T...`, and then disable `operator()` for it:

```
template<class...>
struct enum_wrapper{using type = int;};

template <typename T0, typename... T1>
struct enum_wrapper<T0, T1...> {
   typedef T0 type;
};

//...

template <bool activate = (sizeof...(T) > 0)>
std::enable_if_t<activate, int>&
operator()(const typename enum_wrapper<T...>::type& e)
{ return x[static_cast<std::size_t>(e)]; }
```

And then we could call it like so:

```
data<3> a; // no operator()

data<3, int> b; // operator() viable
b.x[0] = 1;
b.x[1] = 3;
b.x[2] = 5;
std::cout << b(1) << std::endl; // print '3'
```

#### [Better Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9mclKpoFGhiEp7XN)

(I made member `x` `public` for testing purposes)

---

In the end, it may be easier to simply move the condition that your argument to `operator()` is of the type `enum_wrapper<T...>::type` into a `static_assert` within the function that is protected by your `bool activate`:

```
template <class U, bool activate = (sizeof...(T) > 0)>
std::enable_if_t<activate, int>&
operator()(const U& e)
{
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<U, typename enum_wrapper<T...>::type>, L"argument type to operator() is incorrect");
   return x[static_cast<std::size_t>(e)]; 
}
```

You can call it like before, and there's still no `operator()` defined for `a`. If you tried to call `b(2.0)`, though, you'd trigger the static assertion.

## [Best Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bZ1AyxeEkvQU6TKg)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I believe that your definition of ```enum_wrapper``` is equivalent to setting ```typename T0=int``` as default parameter, right? I think it would be "cleaner" to define ```enum_wrapper``` such that ```enum_wrapper<>``` does not have a ```type``` field, but unfortunately SFINAE would not work, at least with the present c++.

Comment: @francesco: Yes. Agreed about empty enum_wrapper. The lack of a specialization for empty pack for enum_wrapper is what gets you in SFINAE. Another alternative is to specialize the entire class [like so](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4ltVtASCxFq2HVh7)

Comment: @francesco: See my updated post. We can achieve proper SFINAE when we make the argument to the fn a template argument, but then we defer checking until a `static_assert` within the function.

Comment: many thanks! Interesting use of ```static_assert``` to overcome (current) limitations of SFINAE.